# DIV positioning issue

Tags: html, css

In this website: [bgflirt.com](http://bgflirt.com)

There is a 200px width div containing TEST: `<div style="width:200px;">TEST</div>`. I need this div to be positioned as a column ot the right side of the content below the menu. No matter what I do it just keeps staying below it. I need it along side of it. The middle part must still be able to resize freely. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you reposition it in the HTML, or does it have to stay where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sibling element `#content` is not allowing any room for this element. Try this.

1. Assign `position:relative` to `#content_wrap`
2. Assign `margin-right:200px` to `#content`
3. Assign `position:absolute; top:0px right:0px;` to your `<div style="width:200px;">TEST</div>` element.

Comment: However, this doesn't solve the real problem, because the structure of you HTML is critically flawed.